# Is there a way to define and send a single BIT

Tags: c++, arduino

The Idea is to compare various radio-transmitting modules with an analog coil transmitting signal.

Therefore it is necessary to send single bits for comparison with arduino radio transmitting modules.

I already tried to include bitset and defining something like:

```
std::bitset<1> p(1);
```

But it still has 4 byte size.

Is there any way to declare a single bit?

Comment: An object will never have a size smaller than a byte. The closest you will get is a `bool`, which is probably stored in a single byte, but if you need to store multiple, this has a lower density than other types.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what exactly you want to compare.

Comment: It's very unclear how your "therefore" follows from your idea.

Comment: not enough context. Please explain what is the problem you struggling with and stop focusing on how you want to resolve it.

Comment: So do you want to store 1 bit per byte (memory location), or do you want to pack 8 bits per byte (saving memory but requiring more complex code)? And what does this have to do with sending a single bit value over some hardware? Quite unclear question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No you can not declare single bits. Only in a multiple of 8 (aka bytes). In C++ variables of type *char* are size of 1 byte. If you want to transmit/compare a sequence of bits you can use *char*s or an array of *char*s.

```
char single_byte = 32; // same as 0010 0000
char some_bytes[3] = {8, 254, 1}; // same as 0000 1000 1111 1110 0000 0001
```

To check if a bit is set at a specific position, you can use bitwise operators like **&**.

```
// example:
// check if the second bit of the second byte in some_bytes is set

char filter = 64; // 0100 0000
if (some_bytes[1] & filter) // 1111 1110 & 0100 000 = 0100 0000
// returns true
```